# GET request to https - NotFound. wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, https, get-request

It's my first experience to code for wp7, and I have some trouble with it. When I state **token_req = "http://api.server.com/oauth/token"** it's ok, but when I state **https* ,it can't connect, so I get "The remote server returned an error: NotFound." mistake at line

> WebResponse response =
>   (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);

```
const string results
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string token_req = "https://api.server.com/oauth/token";
            string client_id = "...";
            string client_secret = "...";
            string username = Field_Login.Text;
            string password = Field_Password.Password;
            string token_req_param = "grant_type=password&client_id=" + client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;



            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(token_req+"?"+token_req_param);

            request.BeginGetResponse(GetCallback, request);
        }

        void GetCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState; 
            WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
            using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

            }
            response.Close();

        }
```

In addition I can't connect to this url with IE, which I have with wp7 emulator. =\

Answer (score 1):

Error Not Found is a generic WCF Error message, your best bet is to use Fiddler although from my experience you havent set up HTTPS to work on your service, if you want to setup HTTPS connections you will need more magic, which you can get from

https://github.com/geersch/WcfOverHttps

Comment: **you havent set up HTTPS to work on your service** What does it mean? If I state **https**://twitter.com instead of my api server - it work =\
I see, that this api server has http adress too, but **http**://api.server.com/oauth/token/ doesnt work too.

Comment: basically what I mean is that your IIS Server which is hosting your WCF Service may not be set up to receive HTTPS connections only HTTP connections(Default) also your WCF Service needs some work with certificates etc if you want to make HTTPS work. The reason https://twitter... works is because they have made the changes. I think you need to read up a little more on WCF Services and IIS if you want to set up HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use a self-signed cert?

If so, then you must install the cert on the phone which can only be done by pointing the WebBrowserTask to a remote url of the cert. It sucks but this is the only way.

Comment: you can also email yourself the certificate.

Comment: Isn't self-signed =\
And I dont have an phone - emulator only